# javascript create an image and get its dimensions

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an image in javascript and then get its dimensions from a function. 
I always get 0 0 or undefined undefinde

```js
let rocketimage=document.createElement('img');
rocketimage.src='rocket.png';
rocketimage.id='rocketimage';
const body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(rocketimage);

function getDimensions(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element && element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        return {
            width: element.width,
            height: element.height
        };
    }
}

// using the function on the above image:
var dims = getDimensions('rocketimage');
console.log(dims.width);
console.log(dims.height);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>rocktetgame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="getimagesize.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure rocket.png is coming under "Sources" in browser debugger?

Comment: wait for rocketimage to load by using rocketimage.onload, your image is not loaded while getting dimensions

Comment: you should wait, until the image is loaded and not check the dimensions immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, the function `getDimensions()` was called before an image got fully-loaded.
We use `window.onload = function(){}` or other alternatives like [Jquery Ready Function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to solve these type of issues.

I also removed `const body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` because in this case we can just call it with document and it requires less code, which makes the script look cleaner.

```
<script>
    function getDimensions(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element && element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
            return {
                width: element.width,
                height: element.height
            };
        }
    }

    let rocketimage = new Image();
    rocketimage.src ='rocketimage';
    rocketimage.id  ='rocketimage';
    document.body.appendChild(rocketimage);

    window.onload = function() {
        dimentions = getDimensions('rocketimage');
        console.log(dimentions);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the browser time to load the image.

Images have an `onload` callback that you can hook yourself up to.
As soon as it fires, it is safe to use the width and height properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with setAttribute, worked for me.
I took an image from the internet for the example.

```
let rocketimage=document.createElement('img');
rocketimage.setAttribute("src", "https://r- 
cf.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/186/186280585.jpg");
rocketimage.setAttribute('id','rocketimage')

const body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(rocketimage);

function getDimensions(id) {

var element = document.getElementById(id);
if (element || element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
    return {
        width: element.width,
        height: element.height
        };
    }
 }

// using the function on the above image:
var dims = getDimensions('rocketimage');
console.log(dims.width);
console.log(dims.height);
```

Comment: This is great and all but the image must load first before calling getDimensions(), why not edit it and include a ready function like window.onload(): window.onload = function() {var dims = getDimensions('rocketimage');
console.log(dims.width);
console.log(dims.height);}

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till `onload` event to get actual height and width. Something like this will work.

```
const rocketimage = document.createElement('img');
// OR - const rocketimage = new Image();

rocketimage.src = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e2a/boise-downtown-1387405.jpg';
rocketimage.onload = function () {
  console.log('Height :', this.height);
  console.log('Width :', this.width);
};
```